# XML retornando caracteres estranhos

Tags: php, json, xml

Eu gerencio um código em Php que solicita dados do servidor como um "changelog" de um servidor de um jogo. Porém no changelog o XML retorna valores estranhos. Como por exemplo nas palavras **"criação"** o resultado é "**criaĂ§ĂŁo**" ou **"você"** o resultado é **"vocĂŞs!"**

O XML completo ele retorna isso:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250" ?>
<SauronGamer>
<Count>2</Count>
    <Content>
        <News>
            <title>[22/04] Preparando tudo para o OpenBETA</title>
            <description>Galera com todos os nosso projetos estamos felizes em anunciar que depois de tanto tempo sim! O OpenBETA será aberto ao público! Como muitos minigames e muita diversăo.</description>
        </News>
        <News>
            <title>[NA] Criamos o servidor SauronServer.</title>
            <description>Foi iniciado o projeto de criaĂ§ĂŁo do servidor sauron server de mingames para vocĂŞs!</description>
        </News>
    </Content>
</SauronGamer>
```

O Objetivo principal seria o "changelog" estar no banco de dados e retornar em json, porém não consegui fazer com que quando esteja utilizando o fetch_row ele adicionasse um item no `array();`

Código PHP:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
header("content-type: text/xml");

$comando1 = "SELECT * FROM  `saurongamer_news` ORDER BY  `ID` DESC LIMIT 0,10 ";

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'usbw');
mysql_select_db('test');

$consulta1 = mysql_query($comando1) or die(mysql_error());

if($consulta1 == TRUE){
    line('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250" ?>');
    line('<SauronGamer>');
        line('<Count>' . mysql_num_rows($consulta1) . '</Count>');
            line('<Content>');

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($consulta1)){
                    line('<News>');
                        line('<title>' . $row[1] . '</title>');
                        line('<description>' . $row[2] . '</description>');
                    line('</News>');
                }

            line('</Content>');
    line('</SauronGamer>');
}

else{

}

function line($text){
    echo $text . "\n";
}
?>
```

> Já tentei todas as combinações possíveis como ISO-5859-1, ISO-5859-2, ISO-5859-15, ANSI, UTF-8, Windows-1250 e os caracteres continuam estranhos.

E em C# um código simples que lê isso:

```
 private const string UpdateNovidadesServer = "http://localhost:8080/minecraft/novidades.php";

    public Dictionary<string, string> UpdateNovidades()
    {
        var dicionario = new Dictionary<string, string>();


        XmlTextReader xtr = new XmlTextReader(UpdateNovidadesServer);
        xtr.ReadStartElement("SauronGamer");

        xtr.ReadStartElement("Count");
        int size = xtr.ReadContentAsInt();
        xtr.ReadEndElement();

        xtr.ReadStartElement("Content");

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            xtr.ReadStartElement("News");

            xtr.ReadStartElement("title");
            string k = xtr.ReadContentAsString();
            xtr.ReadEndElement();

            xtr.ReadStartElement("description");
            string v = xtr.ReadContentAsString();
            xtr.ReadEndElement();

            dicionario.Add(k, v);

            xtr.ReadEndElement();

        }

        xtr.ReadEndElement();

        xtr.ReadEndElement();


        return dicionario;
    }
```

Comment: Um detalhe insignificante: parece-me que onde escreveste `ISO-5859-1` seria `ISO-8859-1`; idem para os outros.

Comment: Da no mesmo! A codificação continua com caracteres estranhos!

Comment: @sysWOW32-- este comentário era apenas acerca gralha existente no teu texto: o ISo-5859 corresponde a  "Aerospace series -- Graphic symbols for schematic drawings of hydraulic and pneumatic systems and components".   Vê a minha resposta: enquanto as fontes estiverem corrompidas, não ha nada a fazer.

Comment: Eu já fiz um script que resolve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...isto não é bem uma resposta, é mais um comentário de difícil formatação:

O teu ficheiro XML está corrompido: denota duas codificações diferentes misturadas:

- o primeiro paragrafo de `despription` está em `UTF8` (provavelmente vindo de um original Latin1=iso_8859-1=CP1252)

```
converte( CP1252->UTF8, "texto em CP1252")
```

- o segundo parágrafo `description` estava em formato CP1250 e foi
  convertido para UFT8 como se estivesse em latin1=CP1252  ou seja ficou em formato corrompido:

```
converte( CP1252->UTF8, "texto em CP1250")
```

Portanto : o teu problema é que tens "fontes" em encodings diferentes,
a ser processadas com o mesmo processo de conversão.

Comment: Pra mim, isso foi uma resposta, e excelente, por sinal, apontou problemas que impedem um devido tratamento no arquivo. :) +1

Comment: @DiegoF, obrigado! (o tratamento de encodings vindos legados e de fontes heterogeneos, às vezes é uma dor de cabeça)

Comment: De acordo com o php aqui CP1252 não existe como codificação válida!

Comment: como indicado no texto (na sua parte relevante) o CP1252= latin1 = iso_8859-1. Pode tambem ser deignado por "Windows 1252". O problema é teres doiss encodings diferentes misturados.

Comment: não exite duas encodings!